# What does it mean for an electron and positron to be in thermal equilibrium?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, antimatter, pair-production

My question refers to the following from [this](http://hep.itp.tuwien.ac.at/%7Ewrasetm/files/2017S-Lecture-07.pdf) source:

---

[image]

---

Within this context, what does it mean for a positron and electron to be in thermal equilibrium and why would that mean the process is reversible? Does this mean that their collision would not produce the gamma photons if they were not in thermal equilibrium? I thought the particles just needed enough energy so to not "break" any laws.

Additionally, what does it mean for the temperature to drop below the electron mass? What I understand is that the photons don't have enough energy to create an electron and positron pair following E=mc^2, right?

Comment: temperature is a thermodynamic variable and related to the average kinetic energy . see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/temper.html

Comment: Keep in mind that the author doesn't say _one_ electron is in thermal equilibrium with _one_ positron, but rather that the collection of electrons is in thermal equilibrium with the collection of positrons. As far as I know, it doesn't make sense to define thermal equilibrium for a single pair of particles. As for your last question, it's related to the last paragraph of my answer to your other question here: [What is meant by “non-relativistic”?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/653230/157014). As the electrons become "non-relativistic", annihilation is favoured over pair production.