# What is meant by "non-relativistic"?

Tags: special-relativity, terminology, definition

I am reading a document on cosmology and particle physics (this s the first time I look into something like this). It frequently states the word "non-relativistic" but I do not understand what is meant by this. When I try to Google it, I don't get a straight answer. The [passage](http://hep.itp.tuwien.ac.at/%7Ewrasetm/files/2017S-Lecture-07.pdf) I'm referring to is:

> "This means that away from temperatures where particles become non-relativistic we find that
> the factor of proportionality, i.e. the slope of the decrease of the temperature, is constant
> and depends on the relativistic degrees of freedom. If one species drops out of equilibrium
> because it becomes non-relativistic, then its entropy density (like its energy density) decays
> exponentially. However, the net entropy has to stay constant so the particle that becomes
> non-relativistic has to transfer its entropy to the particle species that are still in thermal
> equilibrium. For example, when electrons and positions are in thermal equilibrium we have
> the reaction:..."

My question is: what does the author mean when he says the particles become non-relativistic? Why does that change the equations he provides as examples?

Comment: I think the author implies that the speed of particles is much less than the speed of light.

Comment: Just enlarging on @M.Farooq : As particle approach C, the speed of light, properties such as mass, time and distance change. For example, if a particle's mass increases, it takes more energy to make it move faster. See  Lorentz factor, gamma. Note that this only comes into play at very high temperatures, e.g., those inside a star or inside a tokamak, or for electrons close to the nucleus of actinides.

Comment: I hadn't noticed you also posted on Phys.SE. Asking the same question simultaneously on multiple sites is frowned upon, so be careful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is meant by "non-relativistic"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/653230/)

Comment: Sometimes just saying "classical" can be unclear because it means there is no quantum mechanics or no relativity or none of both. Non-relativistic is a term used to be clear that you are not considering relativity in your calculations.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The "mass" does not increase in any physically meaningful way.  Please refer to the accepted answer below for a more modern interpretation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In special relativity, the total energy of a particle in free space (i.e. in the absence of external fields) is given by:

$$\mathrm{E^2 = p^2 c^2 + m^2 c^4}$$

The energy of the particle is therefore dependent on a sum of two quantities, the first being the kinetic energy (which contains the momentum $\mathrm{p}$), and the second being the "rest energy" (which contains the mass $\mathrm{m}$).

To simplify calculations, in some cases we can approximate the energy by just calculating the biggest term. When the kinetic energy of a particle is much smaller than its rest energy (specifically, when $\mathrm{p \ll mc}$), then $\mathrm{E^2 = p^2 c^2 + m^2 c^4 \approx m^2 c^4}$, from which $\mathrm{E \approx mc^2}$. This is the so-called "non-relativistic limit", where classical mechanics is a good description. This turns out to be the case for most of chemistry. Particles said to be "non-relativistic" obey this approximation with good accuracy.

For completeness, the kinetic energy of a particle can also be much greater than its rest energy ($\mathrm{p \gg mc}$), such that $\mathrm{E^2 = p^2 c^2 + m^2 c^4 \approx p^2 c^2}$, from which $\mathrm{E \approx pc}$. This is called the "ultra-relativistic limit", which for most particles is only applicable in extreme conditions (e.g. astrophysical events). Lastly, if a particle has kinetic energy similar to its rest energy ($\mathrm{p \approx mc}$), then no simplification can be made. The term "relativistic" is often used to indicate that special relativity cannot be ignored.